# svn dump file seems to be malformed or wrong format

Tags: svn

I'm trying to get an svn dump of the content of my [assembla](http://www.assembla.com) SVN repository.  I've followed [their instructions](https://articles.assembla.com/using-subversion/getting-started/assembla-svn-dump-files), and downloaded the tar.gz file that the export generates.

I'd like to run svndumpfilter on the dump before importing it to another repo, but everything I do generates some errors;

- if I run `tar xzf` on the file, I get all the contents (a directory, not a flat file) - if I then put these contents in a directory and run svndumpfilter I get an error `svndumpfilter: E000021: Can't read stream: Is a directory`
- if I only uncompress (and not untar) the gz file, and then try running svndumpfilter on the tar file I get `svndumpfilter: E140001: Malformed dumpfile header 'breakout.ini'`
- if I try and download a dump directly using `svnrdump dump http://subversion.assembla.com/svn/<repo_name>/` then I get the error:

  ```
  * Dumped revision 6. svnrdump: E175002: REPORT of  
  'http://subversion.assembla.com/svn/<repo_name>': Could not read response body: Connection reset by peer (http://subversion.assembla.com)
  ```

  this consistently happens after dumped revision 6.
- If I try and import the uncompressed file into a local repo, I get

  ```
  $ sudo svnadmin create my_repo
  $ sudo svnadmin load --force-uuid my_repo < repo_download.tar.gz
  svnadmin: E140001: Malformed dumpfile header '?\8'
  ```

Locally, I'm using svn version 1.7.4, on Ubuntu. I don't know what version assembla use.

Is there something obvious that I'm missing, or are they confusing things by tarring up the contents that should be a flat dump file?

Running tree on the uncompressed download gives:

```
tree -d
.
âââ tmp
    âââ db
    âÂ Â  âââ node-origins
    âÂ Â  âââ revprops
    âÂ Â  âÂ Â  âââ 0
    âÂ Â  âââ revs
    âÂ Â  âÂ Â  âââ 0
    âÂ Â  âââ transactions
    âÂ Â  âââ txn-protorevs
    âââ hooks
    âÂ Â  âââ post-commit.d
    âÂ Â  âââ post-revprop-change.d
    âÂ Â  âââ pre-commit.d
    âââ locks

14 directories
```

Comment: Be careful - "zip" is a specific type of archive & compression. You cannot "unzip" a tar archive, or gzip compressed data.

Comment: "_I run tar xzf on the file, I get all the contents (a directory, not a flat file)_" it sounds like you may have downloaded a snapshot of the repository's files (checked out), or perhaps a copy of the backend SVN repository. Please post a listing/screenshot or description telling us what files you see.

Comment: @Attie I've provided the output from running `tree` - is this enough info?

Comment: This looks like a very stripped (no revisions, missing format & uuid) copy of the backend SVN repository... (similar to what you'd get from `svnadmin create ${NAME}`... can you try again, following their steps to be sure that you're doing it correctly? It's possible that they're giving you duff data.

Comment: Running `file` on a plain (not compressed) dump should give you something like this: `Subversion dumpfile (version: 2)` - it is a single file that should be fed into `svnadmin load`

Comment: Oops, I ran `tree` with the `-d` option for brevity... the `db` directory actually contains a `rev\0\` directory which contains a file for each revision; running `file` on 71 returns `71: data`. Trying to import this into a new repo results in `svnadmin: E140001: Malformed dumpfile header 'DELTA 69 444409853 344'`

Comment: in this case, it is quite probably a SVN repository... try `svn checkout file://$(pwd)/tmp` and see what happens...

Comment: @Attie yes! It is! I really hadn't realised you could export a whole repo like that - at least I now know what one looks like :)

Comment: Great news! Please accept my updated answer if you feel I deserve it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

From your extra-extra information, it turns out that you've downloaded a whole "*backend*" SVN repository. As discussed in the comments, try checking it out with the following command:

```
svn checkout file://$(pwd)/tmp ./checkout
```

---

From your extra information, it looks like you've downloaded the wrong thing, or the download service is broken at their end.

`svnrdump` should work, but it might be worth trying to mirror the remote repository to a local repository instead:

```bsh
svnadmin create mirror
echo '#!/bin/true' > mirror/hooks/pre-revprop-change
chmod +x mirror/hooks/pre-revprop-change
svnsync init file://$(pwd)/mirror http://subversion.assembla.com/svn/${repo_name}
svnsync sync file://$(pwd)/mirror
```

Unfortunately, you may find that this trips at/after revision 6 too, but it's worth a go - perhaps the problem revision is particularly large?

If `svnsync` also trips, are you able to check out the problematic revision normally?

```bsh
svn checkout -r 6 http://subversion.assembla.com/svn/${repo_name} ./my_repo
```

**NOTE:** it's possible that rev 6 is fine, and the problem is actually with rev 7, so try that too.